# Http-post mehod is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When i do a `http-post` request from a `html form` it was working. But when i do this using `javascript` it throw a error like this

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.something.php' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I `inspect` element and copy as `cUrl` and try in `Postman` and it working.Please help if i am doing any mistake

my html code

```
<html>
<head>

<form action="https://www.something.php" method="POST" >
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <center></center>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

    <label for="categoryId"><b>categoryId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter categoryId" name="categoryId" required>

    <button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
  </div>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

  $(function() {
    var people = [];

    var userId=$('#userId').val();
    var categoryId=$('#categoryId').val();

    $.post('https://www.something.php',{userId:5 , categoryId:50},function(data) {
      $.each(data.video, function(i, f) {

        var link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ f.video;       
        var tblRows = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + f.videoName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.time + "</td>"  +
          "<td>" + f.videoDuration + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.liveStatus + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+link+"</a></td>" + "</tr>";
        $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

      });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="profile">
      <table id= "userdata" width="50%" border="2">
        <thead>
          <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>TIME</th>           
          <th>DURACTION</th>
          <th>LIVE STATUS</th>
          <th>LINK</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the issue, but the structure of the document looks very odd. First off, don't put HTML inside the `<head>`. HTML goes in the `<body>`. You also never close the body tag but have a  `</div>` too many in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `CORS` issue blocked by your browser. You can read about why and how CORS works [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

The short explanation is that it's happening because the server/back-end does not trust your front-end.

To prevent this from happening you can do:

1. *Not suggested. as it will fix the issue only on your browser.*  
   Disable `CORS` check for your browser. You can use this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) here.
2. Modify the backend code to allow requests from your IP/URL. You can learn more about that [here](https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b) if you're using Node.

If you are in the mood to jump into the depths of CORS. Feel free to check out these links

1. https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-cors
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/
3. https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: sir can you your code  in my code and paste full code i am new in programming

Comment: I would if I could. But the backend is blocking the request. You can install the extension to make it work on your machine. :)

Comment: please post in answer box

Comment: Read Point 1 of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you can't request a resource on another origin if there is no XORS-Headers present.

Add a XORS-Header to the file you are requesting (in this case "something.php", for example:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;
```

This allows access to this resource from all domains, you should only allow from the domain you are requesting from, so for example:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: mywebsite.com;
```

Comment: sir can you put this in my code and paste full code i am new in programming

Comment: all you have to do is put "header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;" after "<?php" in something.php

you dont have to make any changes in the code you posted

Comment: `$.post('https://www.something.php',"header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *;" , {userId:5 , categoryId:280} ` is correct i think not

Comment: no, you dont have to change anything in the code you posted, you have to change the code thats in something.php (which is another file on another server)

Comment: something.php i cant change it please give another soluation

Answer (score 0):

First thing - the structure you are following is wrong.You should not put the contents which will be displayed on browser inside the head tag.
Head tag should only contain meta tags and other hidden information like viewport and other.

Is the url "https://www.something.php" on the same server, from where you are calling it? Or is it on a different server?

If the html file and the php file are on the same place then you should not be receiving this error.Try running the html file from localhost and not by using the file full path.
Ex - If your html file is not in under var/www folder then move it there and run the file, it should not give you cors error anymore if both of the files are on same server.
I tried running your code from localhost and it works.

If you are calling this server from your local machine or from any different system, then there are chances you will CORS error, if you do not provide the below in the headers.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourwebsiteurl.com
```

This happens because by default all the servers block any XMLHTTP REQUEST coming from other domains.This is done for security purpose.

If you have access to the other server, then you can just add the allow origin in the headers of that servers php config.

I have created some code using curl, please have a look and try it in your code.

Looking at your code it looks like you are hitting something.php and getting some content to bind in the below table with id="userdata"

So first if you have created a html page than you will have to create a new php page.
Copy everything that you have in the html file, just remove all the ajax activity.
Now paste the below code before the section where you are creating the table

```
<?php
// make sure you have curl extension enable in you php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.something.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// In real life you should use something like:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
     http_build_query(array('userId' => 5,'categoryId'=>50)));

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

The $server_output will contain the data returned from the above used url.Further parse the data using for loop and generate the table data which you want to bind.
The tr and td will be generated inside a for loop.

I cannot do the further work as i do not have any reference of data or the url, so you are on your own from here.

I have updated your code along with the structure and placed the contents at right place.Please have a look at the below code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.something.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
     http_build_query(array('userId' => 5,'categoryId'=>50)));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

?>
<form action="https://www.something.php" method="POST" >
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
<center></center>
</div>
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
<label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

<label for="categoryId"><b>categoryId</b></label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter categoryId" name="categoryId" required>

<button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
</div>

</form>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
  <table id= "userdata" width="50%" border="2">
    <thead>
      <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>TIME</th>           
      <th>DURACTION</th>
      <th>LIVE STATUS</th>
      <th>LINK</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- here you will loop through the data you have received from curl and fill it in the tbody, and this entrie thing will be done when the page loads -->
    <?php foreach ($server_output as $value) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?= $value['key'] ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: https://www.something.php suppose it is a site that show temprature from different location as per user input. IN MY CODE WHEN I click on button Get data it working but not working in javascript

Comment: please edit my code as you like because i am new in programming

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourwebsiteurl.com` where in code i have to put it i have no idea

Comment: can you share the reference website you are trying to access using ajax?

Comment: no sir sorry it will not possible because of security

Comment: @RAMAN Access control has to be allowed from the server.You cannot do that from html or js request.If the server does not allow control origin, then you cannot access it using ajax.

Comment: Your only option then I guess is to do the request with php and not javascript

Comment: `<form action="https://www.something.php" method="POST" >
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <center></center>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

    <label for="categoryId"><b>categoryId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter categoryId" name="categoryId" required>

    <button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
  </div>

</form>` is working fine

Comment: It is working with GET request because not all HTTP request triggers CORS preflight. The server must have allowed cors for GET request but blocked for POST.

Comment: If you have no control over the server, then your only option is to change from ajax request to PHP request.

Comment: call that url from php and use curl to get data from that domain.

Comment: @Shabbir and  please make my mode in php and then json show in a table format

Comment: @jogoe and  please make my mode in php and then json show in a table format

Comment: @RAMAN please check the answer that i have added

Comment: sir if you have time then please update your code in my code so that it can work in one click i will be thankful to you

Comment: @Shabbir sir if you have time then please update your code in my code so that it can work in one click i will be thankful to you

Comment: @RAMAN i cannot provide you the code that would work in one click, as i dont know what data are you getting and from where, so you will have to make changes to some part at your end.
Although i would edit the code and make it easier for you to understand

Comment: @Shabbir thanks for response. But sir code given by you giving me a syntax error please execute this code in your system. i copied your code and paste it and name the file as index.html

Comment: @RAMAN i have already mentioned in my answer that if you have a html page then you need to create a new php page and paste the content in that page and run it.Also i cannot execute the code as i do not have the data to execute and test it, if you want me to execute and test it for you then you will have to at least provide me the url which you are hitting.